# Extract Filenames (without extension) from XML File

Tags: xml, bash, sed, awk

I have the following XML output when I grep for "Server":

```
<Server id="1" src="/other/Server/PRX01/PRX01.xml"/>
<Server id="2" src="/other/Server/PRX01/PRX02.xml"/>
<Server id="3" src="/other/Server/PRX01/PRX03.xml"/>
<Server id="4" src="/other/Server/PRX01/PRX04.xml"/>
```

I need to be able to take this output and sed/awk or some other tool, and just get the filename, without the path or extension.  So my output would need to be (for this example):

```
PRX01
PRX02
PRX03
PRX04
```

Comment: If your source is an XML document, what about using XSLT/XPath? What OS are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple to do with awk and sed, assuming the data is in the file "test.data":

```
cat test.data | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $5}'  | sed 's/\..*//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

For the example input data, the following sed script will work:

```
sed -e 's/.*\/\(.*\)\.xml.*/\1/g' t.tmp
```

The `.*\/` matches up to a forward slash (greedy).  Then `\(.*\)\.xml` matches the last of the line and grabs the base file name in a group.  The `\1` tells it to substitute all of that for what was in the group.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer can be simplified without the useless cat and sed,

```
awk '{gsub(/\..*/,"",$5) ;print $5}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>gawk -F"/" "{ split($5,a,\".\"); print a[1]}" 1.t
PRX01
PRX02
PRX03
PRX04
```